# Need help debugging a huge chunk of JSON data

Tags: php, json

I have a huge chunk, so large that I can't manually edit the file and need to read it in and do regex operations to see what's wrong.

Basically - my server is PHP 5.1.6 and I can't update it. This features an older `json_decode` which is less featured than the 5.2/5.3 versions.

`json_decode` returns NULL and `json_last_error` is being invoked but the function doesn't exist except in PHP 5.3 so I'm manually trying to see what's wrong.

```
$regex = '#[^0-9"$a-zA-Z{:}().]#';
$json = preg_replace( $regex, '', $json );
$tree = json_decode ( $json, true );

var_dump($tree); // NULL
```

A snippet of the JSON.. somewhere in the middle

> {"109":0,"103":1,"102":59,"101":70,"100":4299,"94":0,"50":51,"46":0,"45":0,"44":0,"43":0,"42":0,"23":0,"22":0,"18":0,"17":1,"16":1,"13":160,"8":4298}},"2":{"d":{"109":0,"103":92,"102":54,"101":53,"100":4301,"94":0,"50":4278,"49":328,"46":1,"45":0,"44":1,"43":0,"42":0,"26":0,"23":0,"22":0,"18":0,"17":1,"16":1,"8":4300},"m":{"94":1,"100":1,"26":1,"50":1,"8":1,"49":1,"18":1,"43":1,"42":1,"109":1},"c":{"/":{"d":{"109":0,"100":4301,"94":0,"50":4278,"49":328,"43":0,"42":0,"26":0,"18":0,"8":4300}},"G":{"d":{"109":1,"100":4303,"94":1,"68":17,"50":64,"49":53,"43":1,"42":1,"34":0,"18":1,"13":2216,"11":0,"8":4302}}}},"3":

The `}}}}` is suspicious but this probably just closes 4 nested object literals.

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: I'm just starting to get better with regex,but what do the surrounding  `#` do?

Comment: Not sure if you tried it, but both of these tools will load JSON data from a URL, might be worth a try. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: #hookedonwinter - its the denotation of the regex. most commonly its `/`

Comment: @Nate - it crashed for me. I'm trying to load smaller snippets.

Comment: I think I ran into the nesting limit of `20` for PHP < 5.2, most likely. Though I don't see 20 direct nests it probably adds up.

Comment: If it's not sensitive data then you should consider uploading the whole thing somewhere so that others can have a crack at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the data several times through the JSON formatter/validator and it was valid. The dataset is too huge that even using VIM to kill nested objects is a lot of work.

I was able to run this dataset locally, so I'm going to conclude it is an issue with the nested limit of 20 for PHP 5.1 where it gets bumped up in PHP 5.2 and 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [PEAR Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON) class?  It may give you a more useful error, and runs well on older versions of PHP.